# jinja2 partial escape {% and '

Tags: python, jinja2, jinja2-cli

i want to escape the following complete string using jinja2

```
{% set src_pk = metadata_dict['src_pk'] -%}
```

the following works, iam using double quotes

```
{{"{% set source_model = metadata_dict['source_model'] -%}"}}
```

however i want to change the `['source_model']` dynamically so i tried the following and none of them seems to work

1. `{{"{% set source_model = metadata_dict['{{POLICY_HK}}'] -%}"}}`, which does not work and print it out as is.
2. `{{"{% set source_model = metadata_dict['"+ {{ POLICY_HK }} +"'] -%}"}}`
   jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ':', got '}'
3. `{{"{% set source_model = metadata_dict["+''{{ POLICY_HK }}+''"] -%}"}}`  expected token 'end of print statement', got '{'

any pointers please?

Thanks -Nen

Comment: `"{% ..." + POLICY_HK + "... %}"`…!?

Comment: I'd question why you're trying to generate templates from templates though… 